# I asked a question then later found a blog post on the web that perfectly answers the question: Can I copy-paste the content of the article?

Tags: support, answers, external-links

Here is a concrete example:
[What is the difference between using and not using <type>pom</type> for a dependency (in the <dependencies> section)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271528/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-not-using-typepom-type-for-a-depend)

In the meantime I've found a really nice article which perfectly answers the question, and complements already given answers: *[3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps)*

What should I do?:

- Answer with a link? It may be a bad idea, because what if the page goes down in the future?
- Just add the link in the comments? Again: what if the page goes down in the future?
- Copy/paste the article and give credit with the link? If the page goes down people will still be able to see its content. But it can be seen as promoting a site while it is not.

Comment: Give a properly-credited quote, formatted as a quote block to make it clear what's your content? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.

Comment: "What if the page goes down in the future?" - If you have found information that answers your question, on a external website, you should **cite** and **quote** the information.  At a minimum, your answer should contain the information to answer your question, but it should absolutely NOT just be the external information by itself. We don't want signposts. If your unable to provide an explanation yourself, then I can't advise you to copy and paste content, and submit an answer.

Comment: The Option 1 ("*Answer with a link?*") is *definitely a bad idea*! I *tried* it once, and that [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818893/3799241) (>10k-Rep) got downvoted 2 years later, probably flagged as a "Link-Only" Answer and the same day deleted by a Mod. ... Which also got me a -10 Rep penalty in total. And it was (and still is) the only *real* Answer/Solution to that specific Question. The Solution was not mine, I couldn't test it myself, the English wasn't very good (for a Quote), then fair enough, I let it go... (Site continuity and License didn't play a role.)

Comment: @chivracq - So you submitted an unverified and untested link, and are upset, about the deletion of an answer that got a single downvote. **Whole situation could have been avoided by not submitting a low quality link only answer** I cannot accept your only resolution was to submit a link to an external website and that website was the only website with the solution and the only solution wasn’t properly written.

Comment: @SecurityHound, yeah a bit of a *drama queen reaction*, but OK fair enough... I was just conveying to OP that 3 years ago, I was more or less exactly in the same "Situation" like them, and I also hesitated at that time between the exact same 3 Options, I chose one at that time which I thought was "the best fit" for all the Conditions/Parameters, ... to find out 2 years later that that had been "wrong"... Just trying to save that "Frustration" to OP, that's all...

Comment: @chivracq - It’s our responsibility to guide the user to become a helpful contributor to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to copy-paste it,

- you should also check the license of that content and whether you're allowed by that license to copy and paste it to Stack Overflow, where [all user-contributed content is licenses under CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing).
- you must follow [the rules laid out for referencing material written by others](/help/referencing).
- you would do well to say whether or not you are affiliated in any way with the author of that content, or the service serving that content (see also /help/promotion).

---

There's another option that you haven't considered: attribution (give a link and name the author where possible) + paraphrasing / adaptation of how you present the information.

---

To address your thoughts on the options you thought of,

> Answer with a link? It may be a bad idea, because what if the page goes down in the future?

Yeah you have a good intuition to think that. You can archive the page if you're concerned and provide a link to the archived version. Ex. using https://web.archive.org/.

> Just add the link in the comments? Again: what if the page goes down in the future?

If material written by others is a significant contributor to the material in your post, it would be best to put the link in the post itself. See the purposes of comments in /help/privileges/comment. TL;DR putting links in the comments is ok, but if you're the author of the post, you may as well. Others may add links in comments instead of editing a post they don't own because they don't know if adding it will conflict with your intent as the owner of the post (and edits should *generally* not conflict with the post-owner's intent).

> Copy/paste the article and give credit with the link? If the page goes down people will still be able to see its content. But it can be seen as promoting a site while it is not.

I think I've addressed this in what I've said above.